# How to use the default fonts adopted by `\documentclass{standalone}` in `\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}`?

Tags: beamer, fonts, languages, standalone, xecjk

How to use the default fonts (both for Chinese and for English) adopted by `\documentclass{standalone}` in `\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}`?

---

Using `\documentclass{standalone}`, the fonts are like:

[image: standalone-font]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\begin{document}
  是什么 Semantics
\end{document}
```

Using `\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}`, the fonts are like:

[image: standalone-beamer-font]

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
  是什么 Semantics
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\usefonttheme{serif}` into your preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By deafult, `beamer` uses sans serif fonts, you can change it loading `serif` font theme.

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
  是什么 Semantics
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]